# shutdown ssh after certain time (not idle time)

Tags: ssh, shutdown

im doing a school project and im asked to shutdown a ssh session after 5 minutes.
i´ve searched on the internet and i´ve only found the option to shutdown if the session is idle but i want to shutdown when the user is logged in, whether he is working on that ssh session or not.

Comment: Do you want to end the session from the server side or from the client side? From client side it would be easy. Just prepend the `timeout` command: `timeout 5m ssh user@host`.

Comment: i think is from the server side.Is it necessary to change any file or something?